# Android app layout inflating error in below SDK 22

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have two Genymotion devices installed on my PC. One has SDK 19 and the other 22. The example app and the app I'm developing using this library works pretty well on the device with SDK 22. However they both crash on the device with SDK 18. I also have a real device with SDK 19 and they also crash on that device too. The stack trace is as following:

```
10-07 12:24:12.684 9948-9948/io.github.meness.easyintro.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: io.github.meness.easyintro.app, PID: 9948
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.github.meness.easyintro.app/io.github.meness.easyintro.app.MyEasyIntro}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class io.github.meness.easyintro.views.LeftToggleIndicator
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class io.github.meness.easyintro.views.LeftToggleIndicator
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat.inflate(ViewStubCompat.java:200)
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.EasyIntroCarouselFragment.inflateIndicatorContainer(EasyIntroCarouselFragment.java:732)
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.EasyIntroCarouselFragment.onViewCreated(EasyIntroCarouselFragment.java:680)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat.inflate(ViewStubCompat.java:200) 
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.EasyIntroCarouselFragment.inflateIndicatorContainer(EasyIntroCarouselFragment.java:732) 
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.EasyIntroCarouselFragment.onViewCreated(EasyIntroCarouselFragment.java:680) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171) 
      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/toggle_indicators_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020050
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
      at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:57)
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.views.AbstractToggleIndicator.<init>(AbstractToggleIndicator.java:0)
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.views.AbstractToggleIndicator.<init>(AbstractToggleIndicator.java:0)
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.views.LeftToggleIndicator.<init>(LeftToggleIndicator.java:0)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat.inflate(ViewStubCompat.java:200) 
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.EasyIntroCarouselFragment.inflateIndicatorContainer(EasyIntroCarouselFragment.java:732) 
      at io.github.meness.easyintro.EasyIntroCarouselFragment.onViewCreated(EasyIntroCarouselFragment.java:680) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171) 
      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
      at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:970)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
    at andr
```

My XML:

```
<io.github.meness.easyintro.views.LeftToggleIndicator
   android:id="@+id/leftIndicator"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
   android:visibility="invisible"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
   android:background="?attr/toggleIndicatorsBackground"
   android:padding="4dp"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp"/>
```

Comment: what is your xml line 24?

Comment: <io.github.meness.easyintro.views.LeftToggleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/leftIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="?attr/toggleIndicatorsBackground"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp"/>

Comment: This is Project Link:   https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3448

Comment: show some more code Activity, XML put in the question..

Comment: do you have this file? toggle_indicators_bg.xml
and also there is a problem with a color probably in this background attribute

Comment: yes exactly, i removed <solid android:color="?attr/toggleIndicatorsPressed"/> from my layout file.Then it is working fine in all devices.

Comment: I guess problem in color attribute...Thank you!!!!

Comment: glad i could help